# jps process issue about installing Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to install `hadoop` with fully distributed mode in Centos6.4 (I use 4 Virtual boxes).

```
server1 NameNode
server2 SecondaryNameNode, Datanode
server3 datanode
server4 datanode
```

Maybe I guess I'm almost done with it but.. in server1, I typed

```
hadoop namenode -format
start-all.sh
jps.
```

When I typed jps command it says

```
31603 Jps
2930 NameNode
3094 JobTracker
```

I assume that it is fine but the problem happens next..
To get in server2 I used ssh command and I typed `jps` again. It says first

```
27138 DataNode
27032 TaskTracker
27227 SecondaryNameNode
27328 Jps
```

However,, about 2 seconds later if I type jps again, it says

```
27341 Jps
27032 TaskTracker
27227 SecondaryNameNode
```

DataNode is gone.. and at the end it says below after all..

```
27357 Jps
```

As time goes by, everything is gone except 'Jps'.. 
It happens on server3 and server4 too. 
server1 is the only one that doesn't happen.. 
Does anyone have any suggestion for me??